# How to use the databrowse app of django to view spatial data present in different tables of a postgres database?

Tags: django

Usually I have to import a model using this code .

from maps.models import Parking

I want to change the databrowse app that allows me to be able to subscribe to a whole database of spatial data that I can view . Thus "Parking" would change into something else according to the search given . Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it might be:
http://geodjango.org/